# How to implement the Y combinator in Rust?

Tags: rust

I wanted to implement the [Y combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus) in Rust:

```
trait Loop<T>: Fn(&Self) -> T {}

impl<T> Loop<T> for Fn(&Loop<T>) -> T {}

fn main() {
    let y = |f| { |w| { w(w) }(|w| f(w(w))) };
}
```

My first target is just to make the code compile, so I am ignoring the call-by-name issue here. Compiling output from [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/):

```
rustc 1.19.0-nightly (e2eaef849 2017-06-11)
error[E0038]: the trait `Loop` cannot be made into an object
 --> <anon>:4:25
  |
4 | impl<T> Loop<T> for Fn(&Loop<T>) -> T {
  |                         ^^^^^^^ the trait `Loop` cannot be made into an object
  |
  = note: the trait cannot use `Self` as a type parameter in the supertraits or where-clauses
```

I understand why I run into trouble, but how can I fix and make it compile?

**Update**

This question is not a duplication of the linked question, as this question is about writing the Y combinator, not just a simple fix point function. Actually, none of the answers posted there are about writing a fix point function, not a combinator. A combinator must be fully implemented in closures any not using any direct recursion.

Comment: There's an example implementation in [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator#Rust); it uses a Haskellish approach with a `Mu` helper type.