# Why is a reference to a trait implementing the Fn traits not callable?

Tags: rust, traits

I found my own answer to [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511030/how-to-implement-the-y-combinator-in-rust) as the following

```
trait Mu<T> {
    fn unroll(&self, &Mu<T>) -> T;
}

impl<T, F:Fn(&Mu<T>) -> T> Mu<T> for F {
    fn unroll(&self, o:&Mu<T>) -> T { self(o) }
}

fn y<T, F:Fn(T) -> T>(f:&F) -> T {
    (&|w:&Mu<T>| { w.unroll(w) }).unroll(&|w:&Mu<T>| { f(w.unroll(w)) })
}
```

It compiles and fully answered the question. But to make it more pretty, I implemented `Fn` traits for `Mu<T>` as the following:

```
impl<'a, T> Fn<&'a Mu<T>> for &'a Mu<T> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, o: &'a Mu<T>) -> T {
        self.unroll(o)
    }
}

impl<'a, T> FnMut<&'a Mu<T>> for &'a Mu<T> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, o: &'a Mu<T>) -> T {
        self.unroll(o)
    }
}

impl<'a, T> FnOnce<&'a Mu<T>> for &'a Mu<T> {
    type Output = T;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, o: &'a Mu<T>) -> T {
        self.unroll(o)
    }
}
```

with features

```
#![feature(fn_traits)]
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]
```

I wanted to write the y combinator as

```
fn y1<T, F:Fn(T) -> T>(f:&F) -> T {
    (&|w:&Mu<T>| { w(w) })(&|w:&Mu<T>| { f(w(w)) })
}
```

but this does not compile. Error message:

```
rustc 1.19.0-nightly (78d8416ca 2017-06-17)
error[E0618]: expected function, found `&Mu<T>`
  --> <anon>:36:20
   |
36 |     (&|w:&Mu<T>| { w(w) })(&|w:&Mu<T>| { f(w(w)) })
   |                    ^^^^
   |
note: defined here
  --> <anon>:36:8
   |
36 |     (&|w:&Mu<T>| { w(w) })(&|w:&Mu<T>| { f(w(w)) })
   |        ^

error[E0618]: expected function, found `&Mu<T>`
  --> <anon>:36:44
   |
36 |     (&|w:&Mu<T>| { w(w) })(&|w:&Mu<T>| { f(w(w)) })
   |                                            ^^^^
   |
note: defined here
  --> <anon>:36:30
   |
36 |     (&|w:&Mu<T>| { w(w) })(&|w:&Mu<T>| { f(w(w)) })
   |                              ^
```

Why couldn't Rust figure out the given `Fn` implementation? Is there a way to improve this?

Further attempts show it has nothing to do with those features, or even related to closures. Even the example Shepmaster shown in the answer is not minimal. A minimal example is something like the following:

```
trait T1 {}

trait T2 {}

impl<'a> T1 for &'a T2 {}

struct S {}

impl T2 for S {}

fn main() {
    let t2: &T2 = &S {};
    let t1: &T1 = &t2; //This is OK
    let t3: &T1 = t2; //E0308: Expecting `T1`, found `T2`
}
```

The problem is we were trying to implement a trait for a trait object reference, then we need to add extra reference when converting the trait object into a trait object of the target trait.

Comment: Please review what a [MCVE] is, why it's important, and how to create one. For example, your entire example can be [boiled down to this](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=00b2e53268e0527e43aade845148195b&version=nightly).

Comment: Although it is not minimal, but my example is complete and verifiable. The reason that it is not minimal because I just figured this solid example before bed time yesterday, and don't want to too much time before the bed, but still want it to be seen by somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

After some discussion with a Rust developer, we believe that this is a bug of some kind. To that end, we've filed [issue 42736](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42736).

A smaller example shows the problem to be separate from traits. It's actually any reference, not just traits:

```
#![feature(fn_traits)]
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]

struct S;

fn repro_ref(thing: &S) {
    thing();
}

impl<'a> FnOnce<()> for &'a S {
    type Output = ();

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, _arg: ()) -> () {}
}

fn main() {}
```

There is a workaround for this which is to take *another* reference:

```
fn ok_ref_ref(thing: &S) {
    (&thing)();
}
```

That doesn't fix the original example though:

```
fn y1<T, F>(f: &F) -> T
where
    F: Fn(T) -> T,
{
    (&|w: &Mu<T>| (&w)(w))(&|w: &Mu<T>| f((&w)(w)))
}
```

```
error[E0059]: cannot use call notation; the first type parameter for the function trait is neither a tuple nor unit
  --> src/main.rs:41:19
   |
41 |     (&|w: &Mu<T>| (&w)(w))(&|w: &Mu<T>| f((&w)(w)))
   |                   ^^^^^^^
```

That's because the original implementation of the `Fn*` traits isn't quite correct. The arguments are supposed to be a single tuple. Note the parenthesis and the trailing comma in `Fn<(&'a Mu<T>,)>`.

All together, this works:

```
#![feature(fn_traits)]
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]

trait Mu<T> {
    fn unroll(&self, &Mu<T>) -> T;
}

impl<T, F> Mu<T> for F
where
    F: Fn(&Mu<T>) -> T,
{
    fn unroll(&self, o: &Mu<T>) -> T {
        self(o)
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Fn<(&'a Mu<T>,)> for &'a Mu<T> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, o: (&'a Mu<T>,)) -> T {
        self.unroll(o.0)
    }
}

impl<'a, T> FnMut<(&'a Mu<T>,)> for &'a Mu<T> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, o: (&'a Mu<T>,)) -> T {
        self.call(o)
    }
}

impl<'a, T> FnOnce<(&'a Mu<T>,)> for &'a Mu<T> {
    type Output = T;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(mut self, o: (&'a Mu<T>,)) -> T {
        self.call_mut(o)
    }
}

fn y1<T, F>(f: &F) -> T
where
    F: Fn(T) -> T,
{
    (&|w: &Mu<T>| (&w)(w))(&|w: &Mu<T>| f((&w)(w)))
}

fn main() {}
```

I also delegated the calls from the `Fn*` traits to each other to avoid repetition of the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and helpful answer. I have noticed that you use a different style on type constraints (I use inline style, you use `where` clause). Can you also include a brief explain why you think this is better?

Comment: @EarthEngine I find the where clause more readable and easier to extend, plus they are slightly more powerful. Type and lifetime parameters are often very short (single letters) and a lot are crammed in together. The where clause adds some whitespace, clearly identifies that there are constraints, they are easier to skim (I can check each line to see if it's relevant), when I need to add another I can change a line without extraneous diffs.

Comment: I updated the question to simplified the example further. There have nothing to do with closures and the `FnXXX` traits.