# How can I implement Y-Combinator with FnMut in Rust?

Tags: rust, y-combinator

I found a [implementation of Y-Combinator](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f1db7595a2c1f4a5b2f8cfa5a3bb017d&utm_source=wechat_session&utm_medium=social&utm_oi=31673748029440) which supports Fn. However I want to have a version of FnMut.

However, FnMut can not be wrapped into `Rc`, so I wrap them in `Rc<RefCell>`. The following code can make `a[i] = i` in a recursive way. It is the simplest code I have found to test if we can call itself inside a closure.

```
// test code part

let mut a = vec![0; 5];
let n = a.len();

y_mut(Rc::new(RefCell::new(|f: Rc<RefCell<dyn FnMut(usize)>>| {
    move |i| {
        if i < n {
            a[i] = i;
            ((*f).borrow_mut())(i + 1);
        }
    }
})))(0);

println!("a is {:?}", a);
```

And this my version of `y_mut`, derived from the demo.

```
fn y_mut<A, O, F>(f: Rc<RefCell<dyn FnMut(Rc<RefCell<dyn FnMut(A) -> O>>) -> F>>) -> impl FnMut(A) -> O
    where
        F: FnMut(A) -> O,
        F: 'static,
        A: 'static,
        O: 'static,
{
    struct X<F>(Rc<RefCell<dyn FnMut(X<F>) -> F>>);

    impl<F> Clone for X<F> {
        fn clone(&self) -> Self {
            Self(Rc::clone(&self.0))
        }
    }

    impl<F> X<F> {
        fn call(&self, x: Self) -> F {
            ((*self.0).borrow_mut())(x)
        }
    }

    let f = Rc::new(RefCell::new(move |x: X<F>| {
        let mut ff = (*f).borrow_mut();
        ff(Rc::new(RefCell::new(move |a| (x.call(x.clone()))(a))))
    }));
    let x = X(f);
    (|x: X<F>| x.call(x.clone()))(x)
}
```

However, this code can't compile, since `|f: Rc<RefCell<dyn FnMut(usize)>>|` only implments FnOnce, rather than FnMut. I wonder how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `move` in your test code's closure makes it also move `a` into the closure. You can prevent that by making `a` a reference to the vector, and moving *that*:

```
y_mut(Rc::new(RefCell::new(|f: Rc<RefCell<dyn FnMut(usize)>>| {
    let a = &mut a;
    move |i| {
        ...
    }
})))(0);
```

but then the closure no longer satisfies the `'static` bound, as it now borrows something from its environment. You can work around *that* by using another `Rc`, and cloning it in the outer and the inner closure. This version of test code compiles:

```
fn main() {
    let a = Rc::new(RefCell::new(vec![0; 5]));
    let n = a.borrow().len();

    y_mut(Rc::new(RefCell::new({
        let a = Rc::clone(&a);
        move |f: Rc<RefCell<dyn FnMut(usize)>>| {
            let a = Rc::clone(&a);
            move |i| {
                if i < n {
                    a.borrow_mut()[i] = i;
                    f.borrow_mut()(i + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    })))(0);

    println!("a is {:?}", a.borrow());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e8aaddb6dd44c53c8bffaa5766cc621b)

Of course, doing it this way means that you don't need an `FnMut` to begin with, so the Y combinator implementation could be simplified back to the non-mut version you started off of.

Comment: Should `a.borrow()` be `(*a).borrow()`? Otherwise it seems not compile.

Comment: @calvin It [compiled for me](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2a69f3387e7c30fa53e4999e6cc23b86).

Comment: So, If we want to implement Y-Combinator in Rust(which I think is necessary, since in rust we can get `self` inside a closure), we can't avoid lots of `Rc`s to handle lifetime management? Are there better ways?

Comment: @calvin I don't know that, I was just addressing the concrete issue raised in the question. Perhaps the static bounds can be relaxed. I'd suggest looking at [existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42174338/1600898) about the topic.

Comment: @calvin I wonder why you consider it necessary to use a Y-combinator in Rust. While it's a cool exercise, I don't remember even encountering a problem where the Y combinator was the best _practical_ approach. Can you post a new question that describes your actual use case and the problem you're trying to solve? Perhaps we've been dealing with an [xy situation](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Your suggestion makes sense. I actually want to call self inside a closure. [And I already know there are some ways to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946888/is-it-possible-to-make-a-recursive-closure-in-rust). However, I think a Y-combinator way is more neat, since we do not need to change any thing of the closure itself.

Comment: @calvin Ah ok, so, by "self" you're not referring to the `self` keyword (the "receiver" of a method), but to the closure itself. In that case the Y combinator is *a* way to solve that, but I'd recommend to go for the alternative approaches that you're already aware of. The Y combinator is impractical in most languages without lazy evaluation, and especially so in Rust, where it also runs afoul of the ownership model.

Comment: Yes, though a eta-conversion can solve the lazy evaluation problem, the ownership model is quite a hindrance. Maybe wrap the closure itself into a struct is a better way...